# Game stopped working after adding savegame feature?

Tags: c++, game-design, game-mechanics, savegame

I'm trying to make a text based adventure game with my limited c++ knowledge.. But I ran into trouble with saving and loading gamestates.. The functions I made are

```
int currentslot;
void savegame(int savestate)
{
fstream plfile("player.dat",ios::in|ios::app|ios::binary);
player temp;
if(currentslot==1)
{
    plfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    plfile.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(player));
    temp.savestate=savestate;
    plfile.seekg((-1*sizeof(temp)),ios::cur);
    plfile.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(player));
    plfile.close();
}
else if(currentslot==2)
{
    plfile.seekg(1*sizeof(player),ios::beg);
    plfile.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(player));
    temp.savestate=savestate;
    plfile.seekg((-1*sizeof(temp)),ios::cur);
    plfile.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(player));
}
else if(currentslot==3)
{
    plfile.seekg(2*sizeof(player),ios::beg);
    plfile.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(player));
    temp.savestate=savestate;
    plfile.seekg((-1*sizeof(temp)),ios::cur);
    plfile.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(player));
}
}
void loadgame()
{
int plno;
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\tSelect which player to load game from:";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Player 1";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Player 2";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Player 3";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter your choice: ";
cin>>plno;
currentslot=plno;
fstream plfile("player.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
plfile.seekg((plno-1)*sizeof(player),ios::beg);
plfile.read((char*)&p,sizeof(player));
game(p.savestate);
}
void newgame()
{
int plno;
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\tSelect which slot to save game to(If there is no player         1, don't choose other slots):";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Player 1";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Player 2";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Player 3";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter your choice: ";
cin>>plno;
currentslot=plno;
fstream plfile("player.dat",ios::app|ios::binary);
if(plno==1)
{
    plfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    plfile.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
}
else if(plno==2)
{
    plfile.seekg(1*sizeof(p),ios::beg);
    plfile.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
}
else if(plno==3)
{
    plfile.seekg(2*sizeof(p),ios::beg);
    plfile.write((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
}
game();
}
```

With the addition of these functions however, the game() function does not seem to be accepting any values (but no error) related to the class:

```
class player
{
public:
char pl_name[10];
int hp;
int atbt;
int chk_sword;
int chk_bow;
int chk_healthpotion;
int savestate;
player()
{
    strcpy(pl_name,"Unnamed");
    hp=100;
    atbt=0;
    chk_sword=0;
    chk_bow=0;
    chk_healthpotion=1;
    savestate=0;
}
void namegive()
{
    cout<<pl_name;
}
void nameset()
{
    gets(pl_name);
}
void atbtset()
{
    cin>>atbt;
    if(atbt==1)
    {
        chk_sword=1;
    }
    else if(atbt==2)
    {
        chk_bow=1;
    }
}
}p;
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out.. Help and/or advice is very much appreciated.
Thanks